# How to create a webpage in JSP which adjusts itself to different window size?

Tags: html, css, jsp, browser

I created a webpage in JSP and when I run it with mozilla the page is normal. But when I run it with chrome or opera the alignment of the lists and text are out of pageview. How to set my page to adjust to different browsers.

Comment: It would help if you can show us the JSP's generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done definitely by specifying the CSS property `width:100%;`. This will extend layout to the browser width. Note also if you specify `height:100%;` it will adjust the height to the browser height. Apply it to the topmost element of the body. Child tag properties works to layout to the parent tag. And don't forget to use correct doctype as it meaningful for browsers.